# Gradle: Multi project gradle build - During compile of project B invoke method of class found in project A

Tags: gradle

I need so suggestions to solve the following multi project built

**In project A** I have a class of this kind used create web service stubs:

`/src/main/java/com/mycompany/GenerateWSStubs.java`

The class has a method:
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
that connects to some webservices and generate java classes based on them

`In project B` I have a class than needs the classes generated by **project A**

`/src/main/java/com/mycompany/Client.java`

My challenge is to be able to:

1) Compile A before B (easy)

2) Make available com.mycompany.GenerateWSStubs.class to project B (don't know how)

3) From project B build, invoke com.mycompany.GenerateWSStubs.main('') before B dependencies are resolved. (I know how to do it, but not before dependencies are resolved)
This will output some classes to a package com/mycompany/ws/... I just need to make this availble to B before compile

4) Compile and package to jar, project B including both: (don't know how)
com/mycompany/ws/...  (the class generated by running com.mycompany.GenerateWSStubs.main(''))
com/mycompany/Client.class

What I have tried so far:

**A.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'java-library'
dependencies {  
    implementation group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.axis2', name: 'axis2-adb-codegen', version: '1.7.6'
}
```

**B.gradle**

```
    buildscript {
       dependencies {
     //the following seems working but is terrible way to specifying  this inclusion, and the jar might not be there if I did a clean
          classpath files("../A/build/libs/A.jar")
       }
    }
    apply plugin: 'java-library'
    dependencies {  
        implementation group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
        implementation group: 'org.apache.axis2', name: 'axis2-adb-codegen', version: '1.7.6'
       // The following does not seems to allow adding com.mycompany.GenerateWSStubs to the compile path to allow me running main
        compileClasspath project(':A')
    }

compileJava {
        // This should ensure that A.jar is built
    dependsOn ':A:build'
    doFirst {
           def obj = new com.mycompany.GenerateWSStubs()
       obj.main('someparameters')
    }
}
```

Questions:

1) Unless I use buildscript def obj = new com.mycompany.GenerateWSStubs() fails. How can I create an object based on a class to be compiled in another project without statically referring to the jar as I did?

2)  com.mycompany.GenerateWSStubs.main() accept several parameter to know how to read some URL and where to store the stub classes.

a) What variable to I use in gradle to refer to standard resources location (src/main/resources)

b) where should I output my classes generated by com.mycompany.GenerateWSStubs.main() to be sure that they are used for dependencies in project B and packed in B.jar?

Thank a lot